# how to see virus folders

Tags: anti-virus, virus

Its normal that a virus file/folder has a hidden file attribute, but others are just too sneaky that even if you set your folder options to view hidden files and folders, the file/folder which has virus can't still be seen. Is there anything, any application that can make me see these files/folders. But not making use of antivirus software. 
-Im just looking for alternative ways. Because using antivirus software is the traditional way to see those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make changes in your Windows Settings, There is another way to find out these changes by monitoring them.

You can use any Directory / File monitoring software like [FileGuard](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/FileGuard-Download-28844.html) or [Monidir](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/Monidir-Download-10342.html) to monitor the file attribute changes.

Answer (score 1):

What on earth is a Virus Folder? Folders are containers of other files and folders. A virus isn't always a file called **Evil.EXE** either. They can be hidden in perfectly normal files as macros for example. Your assumption that viruses are meant to be visible as files is completely false. Remember antiviruses use signatures (data unique to the virus) to track them. If your looking to find extra files then try unticking "Hide protected system files". I honestly do recommend you stick to an antivirus such as Microsoft Security Essentials or Comodo, either that or you clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command,

```
attrib -r -s -h -a  <your/virus/folder>
```